# Remote Ubuntu Screen sharing from Mac

Tags: screen-sharing

I want to connect to an Ubuntu machine from MAC far far away! I have the application Remoter that works like a charm for ssh and connecting to other Mac. However I don't know how to connect to an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: what is "the application Remoter"?

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, you'll need to:

1. Set up a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc) server on the Ubuntu machine. This is the software that shares the screen.
2. Set up a means of connecting remotely to the Ubuntu machine. If you can already SSH in, that's the best way, you can forward the VNC port over SSH by running this on your Mac: `ssh username@ubuntuhostname -L 5900:localhost:5900`, replacing the `username` and `ubuntuhostname` as appropriate.
3. Connect with VNC to the tunnel. You can do this with whatever client you like (including OS X's built in screen sharing), but the important part is that the hostname to connect to is `localhost` and you use port `5900`.

If you need more specific instructions, I suggest you do a search, as most of these topics have been covered in some detail elsewhere. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=vnc+osx) is the best place to go if you need Ubuntu-specific information.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 on a PC, local wifi to Mac OS X, 10.7.5, onto which I've just added a Logitech K800. And I have to sit up straight to type this in. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90300/remote-ubuntu-screen-sharing-from-mac/90306#90306

Answer (score 2):

While the native way has been described correctly in the [answer by robmathers above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90306/2418), you could simply install the same version of [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) (currently that means installing version 8) on both Ubuntu and your Mac to get around the hassle of correctly setting up Firewalls, SSH tunnels and the VNC server. TeamViewer is free for private use.